# Sandwich Package is not Working Properly

Tags: regression, robust-standard-error, sandwich

The `sandwich` package in R is not working properly. All of the following methods are giving the same results:

1. Regular standard error
2. Robust (HC1)Standard
3. One way Clustered
4. Two way Clustered

This is the code I used :

```
# Load data 
library(pacman)
p_load(data.table, fixest, magrittr, sandwich)
set.seed(1)
data(airquality)
aq = airquality
view(aq)

## Run regressions  -----------------------------------------------------------
est_c0 = feols(Ozone ~ Solar.R, data = aq)

est_c1 = feols(Ozone ~ Solar.R + Wind, data = aq)

## Standard errors (just using fixest)------------------------------------------
etable(est_c0, est_c1, se = "standard")                # Regular Standard Errors

etable(est_c0, est_c1, se = "hetero")                  # Robust (HC1) Standard Errors

etable(est_c0, est_c1, se = "cluster",                 # One way Clustered 
       cluster = c("Month"))

etable(est_c0, est_c1, se = "twoway",                  # Two way Clustered
       cluster = c("Month", "Day"))
```

I get the same results as the normal regression `lm` summary.

Comment: Is it a question or a bug report? If the latter, you should rather submit it to the authors of the package. If you mean it as a question, you didn't ask any. Also, it lacks details and context.

Comment: sorry for not clarifying my question ,  i was wondering why the four different module are giving the same result .

Comment: Can you edit to say it explicitly? Could you also add some context and explain what is your data?

Comment: Note to close-voters: I believe this question requires statistical expertise to answer and should therefore stay open. To the contrary, I very much appreciate seeing an MWE illustrating the problem.